# Young adult fantasy book about two brothers learn magic including paintings that come to life

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

About 8 years ago now I read a book about this community. They had some type of sorting system (think [Divergent](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309/)).

There were a set of brothers who got on this bus thinking they were going to be killed. They pulled up to this gate? All the kids got out. Magic man, huge castle like building. Statues being alive. Endless hallways with rooms for the kids. Boys only being able to see-and go in the boys hall. Girls only being able to see-and go in their halls.

Magic classes for these children. I believe there was a painting class that made real creatures. Parents day- they put up some type of other “picture” for the parents to see to hide the magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like *[The Unwanteds](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9917879-the-unwanteds)* by Lisa McMann

> When Alex finds out he is Unwanted, he expects to die. That is the way of the people of Quill. Each year, all the thirteen-year-olds are labeled as Wanted, Necessary, or Unwanted. Wanteds get more schooling and train to join the Quillitary. Necessaries keep the farms running. Unwanteds are set for elimination.
> It’s hard for Alex to leave behind his twin, Aaron, a Wanted, but he makes peace with his fate—until he discovers that instead of a “death farm,” what awaits him is a magical place called Artimé. There, Alex and his fellow Unwanteds are encouraged to cultivate their creative abilities and use them magically. Everything Alex has ever known changes before his eyes, and it’s a wondrous transformation.
> But it’s a rare, unique occurrence for twins to be divided between Wanted and Unwanted, and as Alex and Aaron's bond stretches across their separation, a threat arises for the survival of Artim that will pit brother against brother in an ultimate magical battle.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you edit this to explain how the book matches the given description?

Comment: https://www.supersummary.com/the-unwanteds/summary/ mentions the bus.